# deleting a collection completely in smalltalk

Tags: collections, smalltalk

I want to delete a collection in smalltalk so when the user selects the option again it is newly created.
This is my code:

```
    "opcion 7"
    /opc = 7) ifTrue: [
        masDeUno:= OrderedCollection new.
        cant:= b1 tam.
        1 to: cant do: [:cta | 
            comp := cta verNumero.
            i:= 1.
            (i+1) to: cant do: [:cta | 
                (comp = cta verApellido) ifTrue: [
                    masDeUno add: comp.
                    break.
                ]  "fin condicion"
            ]  "fin todo interno"
        ]. "fin todo"
        Transcript show: (masDeUno)printString .
        "eliminar la coleccion para la proxima vez"
    ]. "fin op7"
```

Comment: Question: is `masDeUno` a temporary or an instance variable?

Comment: What is `break`? In Smalltalk syntax that would be a variable... Not an instruction to exit the loop. Under the hood, that would mean push variable break on the execution stack, then pop it. A No-op...

Comment: You use twice the same local variable name `cta` in nested blocks. The inner variable shadows the outer. While it may compile, it's generally a bad idea as it could cause confusion to the reader.

Comment: What is the purpose of introducing a variable `i` in the inner loop? Currently the inner loop does `2 to: cant do: ...`. Is the intention to iterate on not yet iterated elements of the outer loop? Something like `cta + 1 to: cant do: ...`?

Comment: masDeUno was meant to be a variable to keep create an ordered collection with the people that have more than one account, then cta is supposed to be each element of the ordered collection masDeUno. The instruction said: make a list of the clients that have more than one bank account, indicating account number and the account balance. Sorry I'm learning.

Answer (score 3):

With automatic garbage collection any unreferenced object will be automatically deleted if there are no references to the object. In your code the variable `masDeUno` is not referenced after the `ifTrue:` block finishes so you don't need to "delete" it (in fact, there is no way to explicitly delete Smalltalk objects).